# Combine multiple lists of items in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Coding in Python and I need to get every possible combination of items such that:

```
[a, [a, b], [c, d, e]]
```

gets transformed into:

```
[a, a, c]
[a, a, d]
[a, a, e]
[a, b, c]
[a, b, d]
[a, b, e]
```

The number of total positions, and number of items at each position are variable.

I've already looked at itertools and I haven't found anything that does this. Any ideas?

Comment: Your input is inconsistent. What if `a` is a list? The correctly formatted input would be `[[a], [a, b], [c, d, e]]`.

Answer (score 3):

So you want [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product):

```
from itertools import product

print(*product('a', 'ab', 'cde'), sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
('a', 'a', 'c')
('a', 'a', 'd')
('a', 'a', 'e')
('a', 'b', 'c')
('a', 'b', 'd')
('a', 'b', 'e')
```

Comment: Nice use of `print`

Comment: This will also work with the OP's input, if it is slightly modified: `product(*[[a], [a, b], [c, d, e]])`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `product` method by importing it from `itertools`.

```
my_list = ['a', ['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd', 'e']]
list = list(itertools.product(*my_list))
print(list)
```

Output

```
[('a', 'a', 'c')
('a', 'a', 'd')
('a', 'a', 'e')
('a', 'b', 'c')
('a', 'b', 'd')
('a', 'b', 'e')]
```

Comment: This works more or less coincidentally, since `'a'` is an iterable, but it will create the product of the _letters_ in `'a'` (of which there is only one) and the _strings_ in the other two lists. If `'a'` were a number, or a multi-character-string, it would break down. Better wrap it in a list.